# Lugaru HD - sound problems

Tags: sound, games

I had purchased [Lugaru HD](http://www.wolfire.com/lugaru) via one of the Humble Bundle deals, but have only just tried to play it. It comes as `.bin` which can be run (after changing the permissions of the file to `allow executing file as program`) in the terminal, to install the game.

Graphically the game runs smoothly, however **there is no sound**.

.

A google search comes up with several [solutions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593685) suggesting to run the game each time via the terminal command:

```
padsp /home/username/lugaru/lugaru
or
pasuspender /home/username/lugaru/lugaru
```

Which plays sound... but horrifically crackly.

Answer (score 2):

Someone on [wolfire's forums](http://forums.wolfire.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6756), posted this solution:

> The problem with lugaru and sound with pulseaudio is the bundled versions of the sdl and al libraries (libsdl.so.1 and libal.so.1), they are either too old or not compiled with pulseaudio support. Fortunately they are binary compatible with the ones probivided by ubuntu so if you simply remove those two files you will force Lugaru to use the system versions and you will have sound.

Delete `libal.so.1` and `libSDL-1.2.so.0` (note the slightly updated names) from the lugaru directory, and the sound plays in perfect "HD".